# How can I simulate the Apple Watch for development purposes?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, apple-watch, watchkit

I just downloaded the Xcode 6 GM, and I'd like to see how my apps work with an Apple Watch connected to the simulated iPhone.

How can I simulate this new device on my MacBook?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you download WatchKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767573/how-can-you-download-watchkit)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

1. Install Xcode (starting from 6.2) ([link](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/))
2. Add Apple Watch target to your project (`New->Target->Apple Watch->Watch App`)
3. Go to `iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> External displays` and select any Apple Watch options
4. Choose `'[your project] Watch App'` target and Run

Have fun! :)

Comment: I have Apple Watch disabled in iOS simulator. How i can enable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005132/running-apple-watch-in-ios-simulator-issue?noredirect=1#comment42539586_27005132

Comment: @MartinoBonfiglioli Have you selected your 'Watch App' target instead of the iOS-only one? This is what did the trick for me.

Comment: Also, I have found that the Apple Watch display only works on iPhone 5 simulator and above.

Answer (score 13):

Xcode 6.0 does not support development for Apple Watch.

Xcode 6.2 supports development using WatchKit.  Check out the [WatchKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH2-SW1) which includes some examples and note issues reported in the [Xcode 6.2 Beta Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6.2_beta_auk9ez/xcode_6.2_beta_release_notes.pdf).  Furthermore, be aware that most of the simulator issues mentioned in the [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html) still apply but were unfortunately omitted from the 6.2 notes.

Xcode does not support development of native apps for Apple Watch, but it was announced as coming in 2015.

Comment: Any reference on when it will be available?)

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Is there any documentation available so we can start preparing / experimenting? I have several app ideas I'd like to investigate for feasibility.

Comment: @EricGoldberg Just updated the answer per today's beta.  You should now have what you're looking for.

Comment: I had a hard time installing XCode 6.2, it was crashing on me. Until I figured out that SprintBuilder's Android plugin was causing it. So I deleted /Library/SBAndroid directory and finally was able to start using XCode.

Answer (score 7):

Apple has announced [WatchKit](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/). Here's an example of what the WatchKit simulator looks like, from the "getting started" video:

[image]

There's also a [WatchKit programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH2-SW1) and [framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WatchKit_framework/index.html), which seem to reveal quite a bit about how the Apple Watch will work.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that while you can't exactly simulate what will truly be available to developers for the Watch, Apple has announced "WatchKit," which is *the* platform developers will use.

Unfortunately, there has been no release date set.

Answer (score 2):

Watchkit is coming out in November of 2014. They will likely add the simulator in Xcode then.

Answer (score 0):

You must have Xcode 6.2+ to develop app/extension using WatchKit.

This guide gives detailed information about apple watch development including how to run apple watch app in simulator.

[Apple Watch Documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/10tdnc5owifbvsl/AppleWatch-Documentation.pdf?dl=0)