# How can you download WatchKit?

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6, watchkit, apple-watch

Does anyone know when WatchKit will be available for download for iOS developers?

Will Xcode 6 include an emulator to allow for a Apple Watch app to be created/tested on a Mac?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: 11/18/14 - WatchKit is officially available on apple's [website](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/). You must download the latest version of Xcode from the developer center.

WatchKit allows developers to build Apple Watch apps. According to apple, Apple Watch apps using the current WatchKit (released in November) must tied with an iPhone app (you create a new target in your Xcode project).  However, Apple has said that later in 2015 it will support independent Apple Watch Apps.

WatchKit will be available in November of 2014 for download. There's still no word on when Apple will launch the Apple Watch besides "Early 2015"

Comment: Today: https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/

Comment: See my edits for complete information about Watchkit.

Answer (score 10):

The Apple Watch is expected to be released in Q1 2015.
A small handful of high-profile social network and services companies with apps on the iPhone and iPad App Store have already been seeded with a pre-release version of the Apple SDK (Software Development Kit) for wearables under strict non-disclosure agreements. One of the developers with access to the pre-release SDK is Facebook, according to a source.

Facebook is also said to be finishing up work on an iOS 8-optimized version of its iPhone app with improved notifications. The social network is also experimenting with ways it can leverage the new Notification Center Extension APIs.

Currently there is no SDK or simulator available for that device.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple Watch is expected to be released in Q1 2015. Currently there is no SDK or simulator available for that device.

Answer (score 2):

WatchKit and related development resources are available to download via https://developer.apple.com/watchkit

Answer (score 1):

Apple will release WatchKit in November 2014. The watch will be released in Q1 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.0 does not support development for Apple Watch.

Xcode 6.2 supports development using WatchKit.  Check out the [WatchKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH2-SW1) which includes some examples and note issues reported in the [Xcode 6.2 Beta Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6.2_beta_auk9ez/xcode_6.2_beta_release_notes.pdf).  Furthermore, be aware that most of the simulator issues mentioned in the [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html) still apply but were unfortunately omitted from the 6.2 notes.

Xcode 7.0 added support for development of native apps for Apple Watch.