# Running Apple Watch in iOS simulator issue

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to run the [Apple WatchKit Catalog example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/WKInterfaceCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) in iOS simulator.

But i have always Apple Watch simulator disabled.

[image]

What i have to do?

Comment: Isn't it under NDA? Xcode 6.2 is still in beta.

Comment: Yes Xcode build (6C86e)

Comment: @gagarwal We don't need to worry about NDA as SO users, that's why SE has lawyers. Also, Apple has greatly relaxed the NDA. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors

Comment: The NDA has been relaxed for the most part.

Comment: @Undo Also, I wouldn't bank on SE paying their lawyers to litigate on your behalf. Better to stick by your agreements ;)

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I'm not encouraging people to break their agreements, far from it, the agreements people have signed are of utmost importance... to them. What I was saying (and I probably could have made this clearer) is that as users *looking at questions* (not asking them), we don't need to take special action to enforce agreements that we aren't a part of. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Undo Yeah, that is definitely true.  Good advice.  If you are not an ADC member and haven't signed anything, go nuts with what you're asking and comment on.  If you have signed an NDA, pay close attention to it.  My general rule of thumb for the Apple NDA is that if a link to provide reference for my answer requires logging in to a secure area or is somewhere other than apple.com, I shouldn't post it.  If it can be found on apple.com without logging in, then it's fair game.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apple Watch is only supported with iPhone 5 and newer phones.  Make sure you are running a simulated device that supports pairing with an Apple Watch.

Comment: I did fall in this pit hole, I selected iPhone 4s.

Comment: Yeah It wont work with 4s,resizable iphone or any ipad simulators.

Comment: I'm using iPhone 6 but still I can't get my app to run on the watch simulator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033588/how-to-run-a-watchkit-app

Comment: I thought it was related because I thought it was a simulator issue I was having but clearly its not.

Answer (score 12):

Go here and click on your app name, in my case it is "watch kit test" [image]

Then click on edit scheme and then this view should show up. Make sure to go to executable and click on "yourappname.app

[image]

Finally close it and go back to the menu in the first step and click "Your App Name" Watch App

[image]

Then run your app in the simulator, and select any of the following iPhones 5/5c/5s/6/6p

Answer (score 1):

You need to to `Editor > Add Target > Apple Watch`.

First, you need to select your *root folder* in **Xcode**.

Hope this helps.