# watchKit fails to run on simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, iphone-6, watchkit

I have made required changes for ListerWatchApp to run on simulator [[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005132/running-apple-watch-in-ios-simulator-issue?noredirect=1#comment42539586_27005132)]. When I run the app it throws an error saying

`The shared application group container is unavailable. Check your entitlements and provisioning profiles for this target. Details on proper setup can be found in the PDFs referenced from the README.`

Even after changing the code Signing Entitlements.

[image]

Here is the link where i have downloaded the example : 
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run the Lister demo after searching the entire project for 'com.example.apple-samplecode' and replacing that with my own identifier 'com.mycompanyname'. After that I had to go to each target and fix the code signing entitlements plus the capabilities

Comment: Lister demo works fine. In the same project they have provided lister watch app. If you run that it crash, sending error message as in the post mentioned above.

Comment: Both the Lister demo and lister watch app run fine after the changing the identifier an setting the entitlements (on all targets)

Answer (score 0):

So what I have to do is run a grep for all occurrences of com.example.apple-samplecode.Lister, right? I got 7 hits, 2 of which are plist-files:

/ListerOSX/Info.plist
/ListerWatch/Info.plist

```
<proj>/Common/AAPLAppConfiguration.m
<proj>/ListerKit/AAPLCloudListCoordinator.m
<proj>/ListerKit/AAPLDirectoryMonitor.m
<proj>/ListerKit/AAPLListsController.m
<proj>/ListerWatch/AAPLWatchStoryboardConstants.m
```

Do I have to replace the identifier into one oy my own in

```
1. all of them 
2. just the plist files
3. or did I get it all wrong?
```

Answer (score 0):

After a quick **Fix Issue** for iCloud and AppGroup in the Targets **Capabilties tab** everything is fine.
This enables App Groups and iCloud on the App IDs.

[image: App Group]