# Can't running WatchKit on iOS 8.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-watch, ios8.2

I tried default apps on iPhoneSimulator.

Running on iOS8.3. But WatchKit Apps not running on iOS8.2.

XCODE says "Waiting to Attach".

Do you know why can't running on iOS8.2 ?

Comment: Max suggested:
Resetting your simulator.

On this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033588/how-to-run-a-watchkit-app

Comment: I tried other thread. but iOS8.2 say's "SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage"

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
[Apple Watchkit simulator issue: SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286571/apple-watchkit-simulator-issue-sperrorinvalidbundlenogizmobinarymessage)

Clean Xcode, because it's sounding like you changed the bundleid.