# Getting black screen on Watchkit simulator and "Waiting to Attach" when adding to existing project

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, xcode6.3

I'm interested in adding a Watchkit Extension to my existing app already in the app store.  I've done my research, followed some tutorials, and now am ready to actually implement.

The problem I'm having is, I can't seem to add a Watchkit App to my existing project and get it to run in the simulator.  If I start a new project and do some tutorials or whatever, the Watchkit App runs fine.  Adding to my existing project, I just get a black screen in the simulator window.  Not even the status bar is present. https://i.stack.imgur.com/utVKp.png

Only lead I have so far is:  In the debug navigator, I get "Waiting to Attach" every time I try and launch the app. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QaWb.png

Any help on this would be appreciated.  I reseting my simulators, tried deleting my simulators and then reinstalling.  Double checked that bundle identifiers and versions match.  Target for the WatchKit App and Extension are both set to 8.2 (I was getting an error setting to 8.3).  Target on the main app is 6.0, but I tried bumping this up to 8.2 and had the same results.

Thanks!

EDIT: Before this is marked as a duplicate of [How to run a WatchKit App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033588/how-to-run-a-watchkit-app), I do want to mention that I'm running the "Watchkit App" Scheme, and I do not have a status bar like in the window like he does.

Comment: We've decided to open a TSI with Apple.  They haven't been able to find any problems in our settings yet.  I'll update when we get it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with Apple, it appears as if this was an issue with Xcode creating the target.  Our app is several years old, and for some reason when creating any new target, the Wrapper Extension is set to "app" every time.  This has caused us issues in the past with trying to add testing targets as well.

We were able to fix the issue by going to the Watchkit Extension target, and changing the Wrapper Extension from "app" to "appex".  Make sure you leave the Watchkit App target to "app".  We asked why Xcode wasn't doing this automatically for this particular project, and it's because the overall project target has the Wrapper Extension set.  If you create a new project, you'll notice that Xcode now leaves this blank.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using iOS 8.2 simulator ?

I had similar error, switching to simulator with iOS 8.3 fixed it for me.

Comment: I've tried both.  Just switched to 8.3 and still have the same problem.

Comment: same issue faced and Switching simulator from 8.2 to 8.3 worked. my Xcode is 6.3.2. May be issue with this release.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your build target is the Watchkit App.  I had it set to the main app so the main app was launching in the sim, but the watch app was blank.

referenced here.

[How to run a WatchKit App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033588/how-to-run-a-watchkit-app)

Comment: Mentioned in my edit, my problems are not the same as his and my target is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I am also running into a similar problem but not on the simulator but on the Apple Watch device. Try setting **Skip Install** to **NO** in the WatchKit App target settings

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, restarting Xcode solves the problem.

Even if everything is configured correctly, it may take 20 seconds to attach the process to the debugger.

Comment: Yeah, we've been trying for over a week now.  Tried multiple times on the same project, different computers, simulators, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but nothing helped. Then I backed up the watch app and watch extension folders. After that I removed the watch app and watch extension targets and created new targets. Then I restored the files from the backup. It's an awkward approach but it solved the "waiting to attach" problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 10.0; Swift 4.2; iOS 12.0**

I had the same issue with Apple Watch simulator. What actually solved it was deleting the default Siri watch face from the Watch App on the iPhone simulator.