# Apple Watch App Black Screen

Tags: ios, watchkit

I know there are [some articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926893/getting-black-screen-on-watchkit-simulator-and-waiting-to-attach-when-adding-t) in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926893/getting-black-screen-on-watchkit-simulator-and-waiting-to-attach-when-adding-t) that ask about watchkit apps with a black screen when they are run in the simulator.

My issue is non-related with the simulator. I had a app working fine in the store and out of the blue (without any update) that app stopped working in some devices. The thing that happens is a black screen when the user opens the app.

When I open the app I do :

```
- (void)willActivate {

    [super willActivate];

    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:@{@"action" : @"loggedUser",
                                                   @"retry"  : @(retry)}
                                       reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
    }];
 }
```

This basically asks for the logged user info. Then I setup the MMWormhole to listen to notifications (in case the response is that it has no user I then listen for a login in the iPhone).

Is this something that I am doing wrong or it is a known bug in the AppleWatch? Like it happened to this [skype's user](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7174475).

UPDATE:
It seems that it might be because the openParentApplication doesn't respond. I will try [this hack](http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/3/11/one-weird-trick-to-fix-openparentapplicationreply) but I have zero confidante since I can't even always reproduce it.

Comment: Are there any situations where `reply` isn't called from the parent application?

Comment: Reply is always called either with content or with nil. Oddly, with the hack I just updated the question with, I can't see the problem. I need to test with more devices.